# Return the list of keys in object if its true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create my own script in React that adds the className if the key of an object is true.
Now I'm using the for..in loop, but I get only the one of my true statement.

```
    let btnClass = this._classNames({
          'btn': true,
          'active': true,      
    });

    _classNames(value) {
                let classy;
                for (var i in value) {
                    if (value[i] === true) {
                        classy = i;             
                    }           
                } 
                return classy;      
            }
    }
```

How can I return the whole list of keys that are true? Also [codepen](https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/YVJaeO) here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is suitable for these scenario, first create an `array` of all the keys by using `Object.keys()` then use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on that to filter out the keys.

Write it like this:

```
_classNames(value) {
    return Object.keys(value).filter(el => value[el])             
}
```

Check the working snippet:

```js
function _classNames(value) {
    return Object.keys(value).filter(el => value[el])   
}

var obj = {a: true, b: false, c: true, d: false, f: true};

console.log(_classNames(obj));
```

Comment: Superb! Thanks! You made my day!

Comment: glad, it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your CodePen demo you would want to return a string with the keys of the object that have a value of true delimited by a space. Try this:

```
_classNames(value) {
            let classy = [];
            for (var i in value) {
                if (value[i] === true) {
                    classy.push(i);             
                }           
            } 
            return classy.split(" ");   
        }
}
```